# how to scrape product data from website pages that uses graphql

Tags: python, web-scraping, graphql

I previously used the code below to scrape the search result for a word search, for example book, on https://www.walmart.com/. They have currently changed their request and response parameters and this code does not get any response again.

```
        params = {
            'query': 'book',
            'cat_id': 0,
            'ps': 24,
            'offset': 0,

            'prg': 'desktop',
            'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
        }

        try:
            data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Sleeping for 10 seconds", e)
            time.sleep(10)

            try:
                data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
            except Exception as e:
                print("sleeping for 60 seconds", e)
                time.sleep(60)

                try:
                    data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
                except Exception as e:
                    print("sleeping for 360 seconds")
                    time.sleep(360)

                    data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
```

I want to get the json response for a product page for example the product the in this url

```
https://www.walmart.com/ip/SKIPPY-Natural-Creamy-Peanut-Butter-Spread-15-oz/37447671
```

How could i rewrite the code with their current parameters to get the json response?

Comment: Bummer you aren't trying to use JS, this would be a perfect job for headless chrome.

Comment: @AdamF can you please provide a js solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your question, to get the json response, You can follow  my working solution as an example. Actually, the hidden api calls json response is [here](https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/browse?affinityOverride=default&page=1&prg=desktop&catId=3920&sort=best_seller&ps=40&fetchMarquee=true&fetchSkyline=true&fetchSbaTop=false). The interesing matter is that the request method is post but it sends query string parameters & request payload/formdata and the next pages at the same time which type of response I face first time ever and I have to make both types of  parameters to get  desired json response. I've also made the pagination following json response and you can increase  or decrease it according to json response maxpage.

```
import requests
import json
data= {
   
   "query":"query Browse( $query:String $page:Int $prg:Prg! $facet:String $sort:Sort $catId:String! $max_price:String $min_price:String $module_search:String $affinityOverride:AffinityOverride $ps:Int $ptss:String $beShelfId:String $fitmentFieldParams:JSON ={}$fitmentSearchParams:JSON ={}$rawFacet:String $seoPath:String $trsp:String $fetchMarquee:Boolean! $fetchSkyline:Boolean! $additionalQueryParams:JSON ={}){search( query:$query page:$page prg:$prg facet:$facet sort:$sort cat_id:$catId max_price:$max_price min_price:$min_price module_search:$module_search affinityOverride:$affinityOverride additionalQueryParams:$additionalQueryParams ps:$ps ptss:$ptss trsp:$trsp _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){query searchResult{...BrowseResultFragment}}contentLayout( channel:\"WWW\" pageType:\"BrowsePage\" tenant:\"WM_GLASS\" version:\"v1\" searchArgs:{query:$query cat_id:$catId _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId prg:$prg}){modules{...ModuleFragment configs{...on EnricherModuleConfigsV1{zoneV1}__typename...on _TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchSortFilterModuleConfigs{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPillsModuleConfigs{moduleSource pillsV2{...PillsModuleFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchFitmentModuleConfigs{fitments( fitmentSearchParams:$fitmentSearchParams fitmentFieldParams:$fitmentFieldParams ){...FitmentFragment sisFitmentResponse{...BrowseResultFragment}}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWStoreSelectionHeaderConfigs{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWBreadcrumbConfigs{_rawConfigs}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSponsoredProductCarouselConfigs{_rawConfigs}...PopularInModuleFragment...CopyBlockModuleFragment...BannerModuleFragment...HeroPOVModuleFragment...InlineSearchModuleFragment...MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchMarquee)...SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchSkyline)...HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment}}...LayoutFragment pageMetadata{location{postalCode stateOrProvinceCode city storeId}pageContext}}seoBrowseMetaData( id:$catId facets:$rawFacet path:$seoPath facet_query_param:$facet _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){metaTitle metaDesc metaCanon h1}}fragment BrowseResultFragment on SearchInterface{title aggregatedCount...BreadCrumbFragment...DebugFragment...ItemStacksFragment...PageMetaDataFragment...PaginationFragment...RequestContextFragment...ErrorResponse modules{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}pills{...PillsModuleFragment}}}fragment ModuleFragment on TempoModule{name version type moduleId schedule{priority}matchedTrigger{zone}}fragment LayoutFragment on ContentLayout{layouts{id layout}}fragment BreadCrumbFragment on SearchInterface{breadCrumb{id name url}}fragment DebugFragment on SearchInterface{debug{sisUrl}}fragment ItemStacksFragment on SearchInterface{itemStacks{displayMessage meta{adsBeacon{adUuid moduleInfo max_ads}query stackId stackType title layoutEnum totalItemCount totalItemCountDisplay viewAllParams{query cat_id sort facet affinityOverride recall_set min_price max_price}}itemsV2{...ItemFragment...InGridMarqueeAdFragment}}}fragment ItemFragment on Product{__typename id usItemId fitmentLabel name checkStoreAvailabilityATC seeShippingEligibility brand type shortDescription imageInfo{...ProductImageInfoFragment}canonicalUrl externalInfo{url}category{path{name url}}badges{flags{...on BaseBadge{key text type id}}tags{...on BaseBadge{key text type}}}classType averageRating numberOfReviews esrb mediaRating salesUnitType sellerId sellerName hasSellerBadge availabilityStatusV2{display value}productLocation{displayValue aisle{zone aisle}}badge{type dynamicDisplayName}fulfillmentSpeed offerId preOrder{...PreorderFragment}priceInfo{...ProductPriceInfoFragment}variantCriteria{...VariantCriteriaFragment}fulfillmentBadge fulfillmentTitle fulfillmentType brand manufacturerName showAtc sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}showOptions}fragment ProductImageInfoFragment on ProductImageInfo{thumbnailUrl}fragment ProductPriceInfoFragment on ProductPriceInfo{priceRange{minPrice maxPrice}currentPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}wasPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}unitPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}listPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}shipPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}subscriptionPrice{priceString subscriptionString}priceDisplayCodes{priceDisplayCondition finalCostByWeight}}fragment PreorderFragment on PreOrder{isPreOrder preOrderMessage preOrderStreetDateMessage}fragment ProductPriceFragment on ProductPrice{price priceString}fragment VariantCriteriaFragment on VariantCriterion{name type id isVariantTypeSwatch variantList{id images name rank swatchImageUrl availabilityStatus products selectedProduct{canonicalUrl usItemId}}}fragment InGridMarqueeAdFragment on MarqueePlaceholder{__typename type moduleLocation lazy}fragment PageMetaDataFragment on SearchInterface{pageMetadata{storeSelectionHeader{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}title canonical description location{addressId}}}fragment PaginationFragment on SearchInterface{paginationV2{maxPage pageProperties}}fragment RequestContextFragment on SearchInterface{requestContext{vertical isFitmentFilterQueryApplied searchMatchType categories{id name}}}fragment ErrorResponse on SearchInterface{errorResponse{correlationId source errors{errorType statusCode statusMsg source}}}fragment PillsModuleFragment on PillsSearchInterface{title url image:imageV1{src alt}baseSeoURL}fragment BannerModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchBannerConfigs{moduleType viewConfig{title image imageAlt displayName description url urlAlt appStoreLink appStoreLinkAlt playStoreLink playStoreLinkAlt}}fragment PopularInModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPopularInBrowseConfigs{seoBrowseRelmData(id:$catId){relm{id name url}}}fragment CopyBlockModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWCopyBlockConfigs{copyBlock(id:$catId){cwc}}fragment FacetFragment on Facet{name type layout min max selectedMin selectedMax unboundedMax stepSize values{id name description type itemCount isSelected baseSeoURL}}fragment FitmentFragment on Fitments{partTypeIDs result{status formId position quantityTitle extendedAttributes{...FitmentFieldFragment}labels{...LabelFragment}resultSubTitle}labels{...LabelFragment}savedVehicle{vehicleYear{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleMake{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleModel{...VehicleFieldFragment}additionalAttributes{...VehicleFieldFragment}}fitmentFields{...VehicleFieldFragment}fitmentForms{id fields{...FitmentFieldFragment}title labels{...LabelFragment}}}fragment LabelFragment on FitmentLabels{ctas{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}messages{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}links{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}images{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}}fragment FitmentLabelEntityFragment on FitmentLabelEntity{id label}fragment VehicleFieldFragment on FitmentVehicleField{id label value}fragment FitmentFieldFragment on FitmentField{id displayName value extended data{value label}dependsOn}fragment HeroPOVModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHeroPovConfigsV1{povCards{card{povStyle image{mobileImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}desktopImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}}heading{text textColor textSize}subheading{text textColor}detailsView{backgroundColor isTransparent}ctaButton{button{linkText clickThrough{value}}}logo{...TempoCommonImageFragment}links{link{linkText}}}}}fragment TempoCommonImageFragment on TempoCommonImage{src alt assetId uid clickThrough{value}}fragment InlineSearchModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWInlineSearchConfigs{headingText placeholderText}fragment MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWMarqueeDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...DisplayAdFragment}}fragment DisplayAdFragment on Ad{...AdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment AdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment AdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSkylineDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...SkylineDisplayAdFragment}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdFragment on Ad{...SkylineAdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment SkylineAdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHorizontalChipModuleConfigs{chipModuleSource:moduleSource chipModule{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}}chipModuleWithImages{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}image{alt clickThrough{type value}height src title width}}}",
   "variables":{
      "id":"",
      "affinityOverride":"default",
      "dealsId":"",
      "query":"",
      "page":1,
      "prg":"desktop",
      "catId":"3920",
      "facet":"",
      "sort":"best_seller",
      "rawFacet":"",
      "seoPath":"",
      "ps":40,
      "ptss":"",
      "trsp":"",
      "beShelfId":"",
      "recall_set":"",
      "module_search":"",
      "min_price":"",
      "max_price":"",
      "storeSlotBooked":"",
      "additionalQueryParams":None,
      "fitmentFieldParams":None,
      "fitmentSearchParams":{
         "id":"",
         "affinityOverride":"default",
         "dealsId":"",
         "query":"",
         "page":1,
         "prg":"desktop",
         "catId":"3920",
         "facet":"",
         "sort":"best_seller",
         "rawFacet":"",
         "seoPath":"",
         "ps":40,
         "ptss":"",
         "trsp":"",
         "beShelfId":"",
         "recall_set":"",
         "module_search":"",
         "min_price":"",
         "max_price":"",
         "storeSlotBooked":"",
         "additionalQueryParams":None,
         "cat_id":"3920",
         "_be_shelf_id":""
      },
      "fetchMarquee":True,
      "fetchSkyline":True,
      "fetchSbaTop":False
   }

}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'wm_mp': 'true',
    'wm_page_url': 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/books/3920?sort=best_seller&affinityOverride=default',
    'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g',
    'x-apollo-operation-name': 'Browse',
    'x-enable-server-timing': '1',
    'x-latency-trace': '1',
    'x-o-ccm': 'server',
    'x-o-correlation-id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g',
    'x-o-gql-query': 'query Browse',
    'x-o-market': 'us',
    'x-o-platform': 'rweb',
    'x-o-platform-version': 'main-176-e8acb5',
    'x-o-segment': 'oaoh'
    }


params= {
    "affinityOverride": "default",
    "page": "1",
    "prg": "desktop",
    "catId": "3920",
    "sort": "best_seller",
    "ps": "40",
    "fetchMarquee": "true",
    "fetchSkyline": "true",
    "fetchSbaTop": "false"}





for i in range(1,25,1):
    params['maxPage']=i
    api_url='https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/browse'
    resp = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,params=params)
    r=resp.json()
    print(r)
    # items = r['data']['search']['searchResult']['itemStacks'][0]['itemsV2']
    # for item in items:
    #     price = item['priceInfo']['currentPrice']['price']
    #     print(price)
```

## Output:

```
'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/deaaef8d-ca7f-4fc1-b556-1209c4c9000c.c6df15d971f1b9cddde27f80f17ae80b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Sonic-The-Hedgehog-Coloring-Book-For-Kids-Girls-Adults-Toddlers-Kids-ages-2-8-Unofficial-25-high-quality-illustrations-Pages-8-5-x-11-Paperback-9781677024223/614029660?athbdg=L1600', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': [{'key': 'BESTSELLER', 'text': 'Best seller', 'type': 'LABEL', 'id': 'L1600'}], 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType': 'REGULAR', 'averageRating': 3.9, 'numberOfReviews': 8, 'esrb': None, 'mediaRating': None, 'salesUnitType': 'EACH', 'sellerId': 'F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63', 'sellerName': 'Walmart.com', 'hasSellerBadge': None, 'availabilityStatusV2': {'display': 'In stock', 
'value': 'IN_STOCK'}, 'productLocation': None, 'badge': [{'type': 'bestSeller', 'dynamicDisplayName': None}], 'fulfillmentSpeed': None, 'offerId': '27E4BA43A8704A1DABF0B37693611D16', 'preOrder': {'isPreOrder': False, 'preOrderMessage': None, 'preOrderStreetDateMessage': None}, 'priceInfo': {'priceRange': None, 'currentPrice': {'price': 6.99, 
'priceString': '$6.99'}, 'wasPrice': None, 'unitPrice': None, 'listPrice': None, 'shipPrice': None, 'subscriptionPrice': None, 'priceDisplayCodes': {'priceDisplayCondition': None, 'finalCostByWeight': None}}, 'variantCriteria': [], 'fulfillmentBadge': None, 
'fulfillmentTitle': 'title_shipToHome_not_available', 'fulfillmentType': 'FC', 'manufacturerName': None, 'showAtc': True, 'sponsoredProduct': None, 'showOptions': False}, {'__typename': 'Product', 'id': '16FA2JT4ZT52', 'usItemId': '491355610', 'fitmentLabel': None, 'name': 'Bible Word Search Books: Word Search Bible Puzzle Book - Extra Large 
Print: Bible Word Search Large Print Puzzles for Seniors and Adults - Beginners Edition (Large Print) (Paperback)', 'checkStoreAvailabilityATC': False, 'seeShippingEligibility': False, 'brand': None, 'type': 'REGULAR', 'shortDescription': '<li>Format:Paperback</li><li>Publication Date: 2019-11-22</li>', 'imageInfo': {'thumbnailUrl': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/46269778-a1bc-4a7a-aff2-75a825e35cf9.62e71231ecd42f6cda6d3701a3281b53.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Bible-Word-Search-Books-Puzzle-Book-Extra-Large-Print-Print-Puzzles-Seniors-Adults-Beginners-Edition-Large-Print-Paperback-9781710478792/491355610', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': None, 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType': 'REGULAR', 'averageRating': 4.7, 'numberOfReviews': 13, 'esrb': None, 'mediaRating': None, 'salesUnitType': 'EACH', 'sellerId': 'F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63', 'sellerName': 'Walmart.com', 'hasSellerBadge': None, 'availabilityStatusV2': {'display': 'In stock', 'value': 'IN_STOCK'}, 'productLocation': None, 'badge': None, 'fulfillmentSpeed': None, 'offerId': '0E3D37D69AE14435A4E83D3AE2789B7F', 'preOrder': {'isPreOrder': False, 'preOrderMessage': None, 'preOrderStreetDateMessage': None}, 'priceInfo': {'priceRange': None, 'currentPrice': {'price': 6.99, 'priceString': '$6.99'}, 'wasPrice': None, 'unitPrice': None, 'listPrice': None, 'shipPrice': None, 'subscriptionPrice': None, 'priceDisplayCodes': {'priceDisplayCondition': None, 'finalCostByWeight': None}}, 'variantCriteria': [], 'fulfillmentBadge': None, 'fulfillmentTitle': 'title_shipToHome_not_available', 'fulfillmentType': 'FC', 'manufacturerName': None, 'showAtc': True, 'sponsoredProduct': None, 'showOptions': False}, {'__typename': 'Product', 'id': '72BDRK2VT8QQ', 'usItemId': '599380007', 'fitmentLabel': None, 'name': 'Trace Letters and Numbers Workbook: Learn How to Write Alphabet Upper and Lower Case and Numbers (Series #2) (Paperback)', 'checkStoreAvailabilityATC': False, 'seeShippingEligibility': False, 'brand': None, 'type': 'REGULAR', 'shortDescription': '9781794540767', 'imageInfo': {'thumbnailUrl': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/535dff68-7946-4e20-899b-20d05015b05a_1.22a1f229111edd3725505c0db3fe1371.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Trace-Letters-and-Numbers-Workbook-Learn-How-to-Write-Alphabet-Upper-and-Lower-Case-and-Numbers-Series-2-Paperback/599380007?athbdg=L1600', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': [{'key': 'BESTSELLER', 'text': 'Best seller', 'type': 'LABEL', 'id': 'L1600'}], 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType': 'REGULAR', 'averageRating': 4.7, 'numberOfReviews': 37, 'esrb': None, 'mediaRating': 
None, 'salesUnitType': 'EACH', 'sellerId': 'F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63', 'sellerName': 'Walmart.com', 'hasSellerBadge': None, 'availabilityStatusV2': {'display': 'In 
stock', 'value': 'IN_STOCK'}, 'productLocation': None, 'badge': [{'type': 'bestSeller', 'dynamicDisplayName': None}], 'fulfillmentSpeed': None, 'offerId': 'B701DAA6361D4A97A599815F29FA450D', 'preOrder': {'isPreOrder': False, 'preOrderMessage': None, 'preOrderStreetDateMessage': None}, 'priceInfo': {'priceRange': None, 'currentPrice': {'price': 6.95, 'priceString': '$6.95'}, 'wasPrice': None, 'unitPrice': None, 'listPrice': None, 'shipPrice': None, 'subscriptionPrice': None, 'priceDisplayCodes': {'priceDisplayCondition': None, 'finalCostByWeight': None}}, 'variantCriteria': [], 'fulfillmentBadge': None, 'fulfillmentTitle': 'title_shipToHome_not_available', 'fulfillmentType': 'FC', 'manufacturerName': None, 'showAtc': True, 'sponsoredProduct': None, 'showOptions': False}, {'__typename': 'Product', 'id': '72DZILK2NY05', 'usItemId': '817841366', 'fitmentLabel': None, 'name': 'Toddler Coloring Book for Kids Age 1-3 : aby Activity Book Boys or Girls, Preschool coloring for Their Fun Early Learning of First Easy Number Shape and Color (Paperback)', 'checkStoreAvailabilityATC': False, 'seeShippingEligibility': False, 'brand': None, 'type': 'REGULAR', 'shortDescription': '<li>Format:Paperback</li><li>Publication Date: 2019-08-02</li>', 'imageInfo': {'thumbnailUrl': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/d2f8e8be-7fa1-4a25-a80c-e1741c6b2f6f.6392f3a67fccf0b396e1fb6ee2848b4b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Toddler-Coloring-Book-Kids-Age-1-3-aby-Activity-Boys-Girls-Preschool-coloring-Their-Fun-Early-Learning-First-Easy-Number-Shape-Color-Paperback-9781086986501/817841366?athbdg=L1600', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': [{'key': 'BESTSELLER', 'text': 'Best seller', 'type': 'LABEL', 'id': 'L1600'}], 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType': 'REGULAR', 'averageRating': 5, 'numberOfReviews': 2, 'esrb': None, 'mediaRating': None, 'salesUnitType': 'EACH', 'sellerId': 'F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63', 'sellerName': 'Walmart.com', 'hasSellerBadge': None, 'availabilityStatusV2': {'display': 'In stock', 'value': 'IN_STOCK'}, 
'productLocation': None, 'badge': [{'type': 'bestSeller', 'dynamicDisplayName': None}], 'fulfillmentSpeed': None, 'offerId': 'D3D88022487D4BF19D540BED3742A75D', 'preOrder': {'isPreOrder': False, 'preOrderMessage': None, 'preOrderStreetDateMessage': None}, 'priceInfo': {'priceRange': None, 'currentPrice': {'price': 6.95, 'priceString': '$6.95'}, 'wasPrice': None, 'unitPrice': None, 'listPrice': None, 'shipPrice': None, 'subscriptionPrice': None, 'priceDisplayCodes': {'priceDisplayCondition': None, 'finalCostByWeight': None}}, 'variantCriteria': [], 'fulfillmentBadge': None, 'fulfillmentTitle': 'title_shipToHome_not_available', 'fulfillmentType': 'FC', 'manufacturerName': None, 'showAtc': True, 'sponsoredProduct': None, 'showOptions': False}, {'__typename': 'Product', 'id': '46CGMFA2PY1Y', 'usItemId': '56172624', 'fitmentLabel': None, 'name': 'Crystals for Beginners : The Guide to Get Started with the Healing Power of Crystals (Paperback)', 'checkStoreAvailabilityATC': False, 'seeShippingEligibility': False, 'brand': None, 'type': 'VARIANT', 'shortDescription': '<li>Format:Paperback</li><li>Publication 
Date: 2017-10-17</li>', 'imageInfo': {'thumbnailUrl': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/d2954574-c30c-48af-8297-900867a2458e_1.03867d2efc65af18a6fdbff418a68afa.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Crystals-for-Beginners-The-Guide-to-Get-Started-with-the-Healing-Power-of-Crystals-Paperback-9781623159917/56172624?athbdg=L1600', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': 
[{'key': 'BESTSELLER', 'text': 'Best seller', 'type': 'LABEL', 'id': 'L1600'}], 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType': 'VARIANT', 'averageRating': 5, 'numberOfReviews': 13, 'esrb': None, 'mediaRating': None, 'salesUnitType': 'EACH', 'sellerId': 'F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63', 'sellerName': 'Walmart.com', 'hasSellerBadge': None, 'availabilityStatusV2': {'display': 'In stock', 'value': 'IN_STOCK'}, 'productLocation': None, 'badge': [{'type': 'bestSeller', 'dynamicDisplayName': None}], 'fulfillmentSpeed': None, 'offerId': '5F59F4B1DE6945728E7F2EC9A3005472', 'preOrder': {'isPreOrder': False, 'preOrderMessage': None, 'preOrderStreetDateMessage': None}, 'priceInfo': {'priceRange': None, 'currentPrice': {'price': 8.99, 'priceString': '$8.99'}, 'wasPrice': None, 'unitPrice': None, 'listPrice': {'price': 14.99, 'priceString': '$14.99'}, 'shipPrice': None, 'subscriptionPrice': None, 'priceDisplayCodes': {'priceDisplayCondition': None, 'finalCostByWeight': None}}, 'variantCriteria': [], 'fulfillmentBadge': None, 'fulfillmentTitle': 'title_shipToHome_not_available', 'fulfillmentType': 'FC', 'manufacturerName': None, 'showAtc': True, 'sponsoredProduct': None, 'showOptions': False}, {'__typename': 'Product', 'id': '7FF8DA7PEPDT', 'usItemId': '136868031', 'fitmentLabel': None, 'name': 'Hack Learning: Hacking School Discipline : 9 Ways to Create a Culture of Empathy and Responsibility Using Restorative Justice (Series #22) (Paperback)', 'checkStoreAvailabilityATC': False, 'seeShippingEligibility': False, 'brand': None, 'type': 'REGULAR', 'shortDescription': '<li>Format:Paperback</li><li>Publication Date: 2019-03-12</li>', 'imageInfo': {'thumbnailUrl': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/4c639aa7-2580-4782-84ce-33a428cae000.571d547af78d39ffc35bdd28f988023f.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff'}, 'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Hack-Learning-Hacking-School-Discipline-9-Ways-Create-Culture-Empathy-Responsibility-Using-Restorative-Justice-Series-22-Paperback-9781948212137/136868031?athbdg=L1600', 'externalInfo': None, 'category': {'path': None}, 'badges': {'flags': [{'key': 'BESTSELLER', 'text': 'Best seller', 'type': 'LABEL', 'id': 'L1600'}], 'tags': [{'key': 'THREE_PLUS_DAY_SHIPPING', 'text': '3+ day shipping', 'type': 'LABEL'}, {'key': 'SAVE_WITH_W_PLUS', 'text': 'Save with', 'type': 'ICON'}]}, 'classType':
```

## Output: Extracted price as example:

```
22.99
1.22
6.99
9.95
5.95
9.81
5.99
13.17
4.52
6.99
4.99
7.99
6.79
5.99
6.5
6.95
6.99
5.99
4.99
5
4.99
11.93
5.99
4.99
6.99
6.99
6.95
6.95
8.99
14.81
5.13
7.29
3.95
5.99
5.5
5.99
16.88
6.99
6.99
1.99
22.99
1.22
6.99
9.95
5.95
9.81
5.99
13.17
4.52
6.99
4.99
7.99
6.7
```

Comment: Oh wow, amazing. This is the response I am getting back for r                                                       
 {'redirectUrl': '/blocked?url=Lw==&uuid=912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73&vid=&g=b', 'appId': 'PXu6b0qd2S', 'jsClientSrc': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/init.js', 'firstPartyEnabled': True, 'vid': '', 'uuid': '912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73', 'hostUrl': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/xhr', 'blockScript': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&m=0&u=912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73&v=&g=b'}

Comment: The data of that particular site is `cloudflare` protected and which is why you are getting such result @e.iluf. Try this library `cloudscraper` which is meant to bypass that protection. Fyi, `requests` library and `cloudscraper` work in the same way, so you can use this library interchangeably. This is how the [modified portion of the above script](https://pastebin.com/ja0d9mZV) looks like.

Comment: I have tried this but it is working sometime and rest of the time giving {'redirectUrl': '/blocked?url=Lw==&uuid=912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73&vid=&g=b', 'appId': 'PXu6b0qd2S', 'jsClientSrc': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/init.js', 'firstPartyEnabled': True, 'vid': '', 'uuid': '912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73', 'hostUrl': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/xhr', 'blockScript': '/px/PXu6b0qd2S/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&m=0&u=912ce32e-5603-11ec-92c4-454758524a73&v=&g=b'}, response. 
implemented this using httparty.

Answer (score 1):

While this question specifically relates to Python, consider using [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) for browser automation. This allows you to initiate requests as the user from a high-level, and you can use [`page.on('response')`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v12.0.1&show=api-event-response) to intercept API server responses.  This could remove the low-level schema requirements that are more likely to change compared to the public UI.  You could also parse the web page results seen by users, which avoids the low-level data abstractions.